# I can't add "blurkit" library to my android studio project

Tags: java, android-studio, github, implementation

I'm working on a project and I have some problems with connecting ["blurkit"](https://github.com/CameraKit/blurkit-android) library. I took implementation from GitHub and passed it to dependencies in `build.gradle`, but when I rebuild the project I have this message:

[image]

Comment: did you add it to **app level** build.gradle?

Comment: @mr1554 yes, I did

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. Just replace the io.alterac blurkit library in your build.gradle dependencies with wonderkiln blurkit.

```
implementation 'io.alterac.blurkit:blurkit:1.1.1'
```

with this

```
implementation 'com.github.wonderkiln:blurkit-android:1.1.1'
```

Sync project and it will work